# Calling value from OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I have a value from the selected item in spinner passed to a String variable **'selectedSpinner'** using `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener()`. I am trying to access **'selectedSpinner'** outside of the method.

I have tried to assign **'selectedSpinner'** to another String **'selectedCategory'** but outside of the `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener()` method, **'selectedSpinner'** could not be resolved. What should be done to access **'selectedSpinner'** outside of the method? Thanks

```
private void recordDialog() {

    ...
    //get category
    final Spinner spinner = subView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.category, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selectedSpinner = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    final String selectedCategory = selectedSpinner;
    ...
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `selectedSpinner` outside `recordDialog` function (or set it as global)

```
String selectedSpinner;
          ...
private void recordDialog() {
          ...... 
     @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         selectedSpinner = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
      }
}
```

After that you can assign `selectedSpinner` to `selectedCategory`.